# After user's cookie expires execute an action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to execute an action after user's cookie expires.
The action is session#destroy. Any idea how to do that?

This is session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store(
  key: '_app_session',
  expire_after: ENV['SESSION_EXPIRE'].to_i.minutes
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem then you can simply authenticate user before action like this. This will check use session expired or not.

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!
```

For manual to check the session is expired or not before action. 
Add this line to your application controller :

```
before_action :expire_session

private
def expire_session
  time_left = (session[:expire_after] - Time.now).to_i
  unless time_left > 0
    # redirect to login page
  else
   session[:expire_after] = Time.now + ENV['SESSION_EXPIRE'].to_i.minutes
  end
end
```